# Error in covariance matrix using scipy.odr regression

Tags: python, scipy, regression

I am trying to use the scipy.odr package to fit data (x,y) which have errors on both x and y, and nonzero covariance between y data.
I compute the covariance matrix between y data, however passing it to the odr packages raises an error.

This is a simplified example illustrating the issue:

```
from scipy.odr import ODR, Model, Data, RealData
import numpy as np

# data (x, y)
source = np.array([ [ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 2.1 ], [ 1.9, 3 ] ])
errx = np.array([ 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 ])
cov_sourcey = np.zeros((len(source), len(source)))
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if (i == j):
            cov_sourcey[i, j] = 0.2
        if ((i == j + 1) or (j == i + 1)):
            cov_sourcey[i, j] = 0.05
print(cov_sourcey)

def model(b, x):
    return b[0] + b[1] * x

starting_parameters = [0, 0]
odrmodel = Model(model)
odrdata = RealData(source[:, 0], source[:, 1], sx = errx, covy = cov_sourcey)
myodr = ODR(odrdata, odrmodel, starting_parameters)
odroutput = myodr.run()

for i in range(len(odroutput.beta)):
    print(odroutput.beta[i], odroutput.sd_beta[i])
print(odroutput.res_var)
```

The error in the output is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 23
     21 odrdata = RealData(source[:, 0], source[:, 1], sx = errx, covy = cov_sourcey)
     22 myodr = ODR(odrdata, odrmodel, starting_parameters)
---> 23 odroutput = myodr.run()
     25 for i in range(len(odroutput.beta)):
     26     print(odroutput.beta[i], odroutput.sd_beta[i])

File /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/odr/_odrpack.py:1125, in ODR.run(self)
   1122     if obj is not None:
   1123         kwds[attr] = obj
-> 1125 self.output = Output(odr(*args, **kwds))
   1127 return self.output

ValueError: could not convert we to a suitable array
```

How can I correctly supply the covariances?

Comment: I read through the SciPy source code, and I learned that the `we` it's complaining about is the `odrdata.we` parameter. It is expecting the we variable to have the same number of elements as there are response variables. So a covariance matrix of [[1]] seems to work.